# Laravel - Eloquent converts query parameter to integer before comparison

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to return a single row from a table based on the primary key.

```
    $product = Product::where('id', '=', $idOrSKU)
        ->orWhere('sku', '=', $idOrSKU)
        ->take(1)->get();
```

For some reason `$idorSKU` is being converted to and `(int)` before the comparison happens. For example, when `$isOrSKU = "9dfghfd"`, the row with ID=9 is returned. Why is this? It should return nothing at all! Can someone explain this?

Here is the relevant table scheme

```
| id                         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL      
| name                       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                
| sku                        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL
```

Comment: Can you confirm what sql is being executed by doing `dd(end(DB::getQueryLog()));` after your `get()`?

Comment: it should work properly check $isOrSKU are you using any type casting? before the query or it is being converted to int before only there is no problem with your query

Comment: This is an int column, what do you expect to happen when you try to find a string on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to the database, not Laravel, typecasting your string. Because you are doing a query on an `int(10)` column, mySQL is forcably changing your search string to an `int`, causing your query to become `9`.

I can confirm the following:

```
$test1 = Test::find('1');
echo $test1->id; // gives 1

$test2 = Test::find('1example');
echo $test2->id; // gives 1
```

Therefore your variable of `9dfghfd` because typecast to `int (9)`. But if your variable was "df9ghfd" - it would not be typecast, and it wont match.

Edit: The issue affects other things, like Route model binding:

```
domain.com/product/1

domain.com/product/1thisalsoworks // takes you to the page of ID 1
```

[I've opened a ticket on Github to discuss it further](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5254) - so check here for further information/discussion.

But overall the issue is not a direct fault of Laravel.

Edit: seems the issue affects GitHub *itself*:

This works: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5254

And so does this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5254typecast

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct answer, but I'm still having trouble to understand why the OP is trying to find a string on an int column. Is he expecting for the database to raise an exception?

Comment: I'm guessing he has a search field, where users can put *either* an "id" or a "sku" (i.e. part number). So he then is performing a search using the input. But the search returns incorrect results if the sku starts with a number, because the database matches it to an ID

Comment: However @AntonioCarlosRibeiro - it still leaves the issue of allowing incorrect URL routes to occur... although not a major issue - it is still not optimal...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really looking at his query, my bad. Added a different answer, not really fixing the problem, but getting around it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that here, using PostgreSQL, it works differently from your database, when I do:

```php
Route::any('test', function()
{
    $code = '181rerum';

    return Ad::where('id', $code)->orWhere('company_code', $code)->first();
});
```

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input 
syntax for integer: "181rerum" (SQL: select * from "ads" where 
"id" = 181rerum or "company_code" = 181rerum limit 1)
```

So Laravel, knowing it is a integer column, is passing it directly to the database without quotes, which generates a database exception, since PostgreSQL will not even try to cast that string to integer.

So, even if you get some help from Laravel core developers I think you should always do something like this to help you do those mixed seaches:

```
Route::any('test/{id}', function($id)
{
    /// You can always filter by a string here

    $q = Ad::where('company_code', $id);

    /// You just try to filter by id if the search string is entirely numeric

    if (is_numeric($id))
    {
        $q->orWhere('id', $id);
    }

    return $q->first();
});
```

Comment: What about for route model binding, where you dont control the input?

Comment: Never mind. Seems the problem affects everyone, even GitHub itself. See my editted answer.