# Why is laravel not putting quotes around numeric queries on a varchar field?

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I have a table that holds customer supplier details.  there is a customer_number field in the mysql database that is defined as a varchar length 6.  There is an index for this column.

Whenever I search for a row in laravel, its as if laravel sees the search criteria is all digits such as 12345 so when it produces a mysql query it does not put quotes around 12345.  This causes mysql to ignore the index and use a full table scan which is very slow.

example search:

```
$RICPCS = \App\CustomerProductCategorySupplier::get()- 
>where('customer_number', $this->customer->delivery_account_no)- 
>where('category_number', $product->product_category)->first();
```

Laravel produces the following sql query
describe

```
select * from `customer_product_category_supplier` 
where `customer_number` = 10626 and `category_number` = 140
```

a mysql describe reports:

[image]

Where as I want the generated sql to read:
describe select * from `customer_product_category_supplier` 
where `customer_number` = '10626' and `category_number` = '140'

mysql describe reports:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: it's php problem not laravel try this $var =20;  strval($var);

Comment: I don't believe Eloquent does so. There are many noobish database wrappers that are snooping the variable's rtpe and bind them accordingly. But it's the most awful thing a database library can do. Binding a number as a string is OK, but binding a string as a number is a disaster.

Comment: If it's a numeric value, why define it as a varchar?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25008004/296555

Comment: its defined as a varchar because its often a number but not always

Comment: @waterloomatt I found that isue while searching for answers, as far as I'm aware there is no fix there

Comment: @stryker how do you get the final query? In the Mysql log?

Comment: Is `$this->customer->delivery_account_no` a string?

Comment: What version of PHP & Laravel are you using? Can you confirm that your DB driver is `mysqlnd` and not `libmysqlclient`? Can you please show us your `config/database.php` configuration... with any credentials removed of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the columns to string with https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

But I think it would be smarter to store numbers as int/float etc

Comment: I do not think that would affect a sql search... it only casts the attributes when they are fetched from the model